# How can I set up a format check in python 3 if i want the data input by user to be of a particular format?

Tags: python, python-2.7, validation, python-3.x, error-handling

So basically I want to prompt user for input and this input should follow a strict order which is precisely in the sequence "One upper case letter followed by 2 lower case letters followed by 3 numerals or integars"
But the code i've written gives an error and this error only occurs when a correct format input is made, otherwise no errors while running it. What am i doing wrong and how can get this done?
(screens attached)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5OsH.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlVBH.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the kind of thing regex was intended for

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{2}\d{3}$
```

**Python implementation:**

```
while 1:
    inputString = input()
    if re.match(r"^[A-Z][a-z]{2}\d{3}$", inputString):
        print("Input accepted")
        break
    else:
        print("Bad input, please try again")
```

**Output:**

```
Aa123      #missing one lowercase
Bad input, please try again
Aaa22      #missing one integer
Bad input, please try again
aaa123     #missing one capital
Bad input, please try again
Aaa123     # 1 capital, 2 lower, 3 integers
Input accepted
```

**How the regex works**

`$` ---------> Assert position at start of the string 
 `[A-Z]` -----> Match one capital letter 
 `[a-z]{2}` --> Match two lowercase letters
 `\d{3}` -----> Match 3 digits
 `$` ---------> Assert position at end of string

Answer (score 0):

In the Validation of the integer part, You are converting it into a integer and trying to make a string method call on it. Try to keep it simple

```
userID[3:5].isdigit()
```

would be enough. But the Best way to do this Validation is to go for Regular Expressions. And I feel you also need to check the length of the string so :

```
def ValidateUserID(u):
    result = False
    if u[0] == u[0].upper() and u[1:2] == u[1:2].lower() and u[3:5].isdigit() and len(u) == 6:
        result = True
    return result
```

Hope it helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: So the ".isdigit()" function checks a string for a digit and not an integar value? And thankyou very much, that helped a lot :)

Comment: Yes @HogRider123 That's what is creating the problem for u !!  :) Happy coding buddy !! :)

Comment: One more quick question here. If i want to define a function for all of this code with the the function name "ValidateUserID" and either get a true or false according to the result. Can you please tell me how i'll modify my code for this? Thanks @san

Comment: @HogRider123 Made the edit in the Code..Please Check !! :)